en vs codde no reconoce las librerias que instalo para usar con phyton
Tengo el siguiente error:

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'barcode'
File "C:\Users\jhosu\OneDrive\Escritorio\proyecto karol\GENERADOR.py", line 1, in 
import barcode
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'barcode'

Y éste es el código:
     **import barcode
     from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
     def generar_codigo_de_barras(codigo):
     code128 = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
     codigo_de_barras = code128(codigo, writer=ImageWriter())
     codigo_de_barras.save('codigo_de_barras')
     codigo = 'ABC123'  # Aquí debes colocar el código que quieras generar
     generar_codigo_de_barras(codigo)**


pip instala los paquetes en el intérprete al que pertenece, tienes que instalar esos paquetes en el mismo interprete/entorno virtual en el que estés ejecutando el proyecto en VSC. En la barra de estado, abajo a la derecha, puedes ver el interprete/venv en uso, debes instalar los paquetes en él o cambiar al correcto. Si abres una nueva terminal en VSC debería activarse el entorno en ella y usar pip ahí para instalar los paquetes en el, o abre una terminal externa, activa el entorno e instala los paquetes necesarios. Te recomiendo leerte https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments
